# CSS Animation Scale works in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: css, animation, webkit, transform, scale

RESOLVED: [CSS Animation/Scale issue in Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801084/css-animation-scale-issue-in-chrome-webkit)

I asked this question previously, but I'm not sure if it was clear. I've done a ton of troubleshooting since to no avail. So I'm back w/ a play-by-play hoping for some help.

1. Using JS, on doc ready, I remove the class that hides the image and add logoAnim which sets the object in motion.
2. The object should drop in with a simultaneous scaleY(2) effect- an oozing/drip effect.

You can see the correct effect in the JSFiddle link via Firefox/Moz, however it doesn't work in Chrome/Webkit. Looking at the Firebug code in FF, the '-moz-animation:2s ease 2s normal none 1 ooze' appears in the CSS of the '.logoAnim'- it doesn't appear in the webkit version in Chrome.

Am I missing something? Is structure/order of the css important in webkit?

http://jsfiddle.net/AfDwu/5/

Comment: Have you the markup/jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Okay- I'm trying, but I'm not getting results...http://jsfiddle.net/AfDwu/1/

Comment: Scaling doesn't appear to work in either browser for me.

Comment: try this on instead http://jsfiddle.net/AfDwu/7/ note there is a delay as it loads the image

Comment: Inrbob- Same results- works in FF, not in Chrome/Safari-webkit.

Comment: Resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801084/css-animation-scale-issue-in-chrome-webkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been resolved by DuoPixel: [CSS Animation/Scale issue in Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801084/css-animation-scale-issue-in-chrome-webkit)

You are not specifying the properties of the `-webkit-animation`, only the name.

Replace: `-webkit-animation-name: ooze`

With: `-webkit-animation: ooze  2s 2s ease-in-out;`

And it will work.