# CSS Animation/Scale issue in Chrome/Webkit

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, css-transitions

This effect works fine in FF but not Chrome- the Firebug results in Chrome show that the '-webkit-animation' aren't rendered in Chrome. In Firefox however, you see the'stretch' effect on entrance of the object. In Chrome, the object doesn't scale at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/AfDwu/5/

Comment: seems to work fine as far as i can tell -- there's an 80% animation point in the webkit keyframe that isn't present in the moz one though

Comment: works for me too as far as FF and Chrome... both results look the same anyways.

Comment: I edited the jsfiddle so the effect is more dramatic. Can you see the difference now? http://jsfiddle.net/AfDwu/26/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying the properties of the `-webkit-animation`, only the name.

Replace:

```
-webkit-animation-name: ooze
```

With:

```
-webkit-animation: ooze  2s 2s ease-in-out;
```

And it will work